# Regular Expressions: Strings of an even length in which all the 'o’s (if any) come before all the 'g’s (if any)

Tags: regex, expression

I'm pretty new to regular expressions so I could use some help.
Right now I have:

`(oo|og)+(oo|gg|og|go)*`

for the alphabet = {o,g}
which I made from a previous task, as an answer to "Strings of an even length, whose first character is 'o'".

Now I have to make a regular expression for strings of an even length in which all the 'o’s (if any) come before all the 'g’s (if any).

How would I do that? Is it possible to modify my previous answer to accommodate the change?

Answer (score 0):

A string that where all `o`s precede all `g`s and is of even lengths can have a few different shapes:

1. The empty string
2. A positive, even number of `o`s, no `g`s: `/(oo)+/`
3. No `o`s, a positive even number of `g`s: `/(gg)+/`
4. An even number of `o`s followed by an even number of `g`s: `/(oo)+(gg)+/`
5. An odd number of `o`s followed by an odd number of `g`s: `/o(oo)*g(gg)*/`

Putting it all together you get `/(oo)*(gg)*|o(oo)*g(gg)*/`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match emtpy strings, and using a lookahead is supported, you can assert pairs of o and g to the end of the string to make sure that it is even.

Then match optional o's followed by optional g's.

```
^(?=(?:[og]{2})+$)o*g*$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6HWzb/1).

Without lookarounds, you could repeat optional pairs of `oo`, optinally match a single pair or `og` and optionally repeat matching pairs of `gg`

```
^(oo)*(?:og)?(gg)*$
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/c4A6K0/1).